# From drop-list lists show only the selected list and its subcategories

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show only the entire dropdown list, but when you select an option, the remaining list is removed and remains only selected is displayed. I'll show you the current code, all I want is when I click on "Main Item One", the "Main Item Two" option disappears and show only "Main Item One" with options. Or when I click on "Main Item Two" show only "Main Item Two" with subcategory.

```js
var allHasChildren = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children a");
for (var x = 0; x < allHasChildren.length; x++) {
  allHasChildren[x].onclick = function() {
    // get the first submenu and toggle using classes
    var subMenu = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[0];
    if (subMenu.classList.contains('selected')) {
      subMenu.classList.remove("selected");
    } else {
      subMenu.classList.add("selected");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 55px;
  background: #153161;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: 12px 50px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn i {
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #8391ab;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn .arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #8191aa;
  margin: 100%;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn-two {
  background: red;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn-three {
  background: yellow;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 330px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.selected {
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-one">
            DropDown
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item One</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <div class="hr2"></div>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item Two</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <div class="hr2"></div>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item Two</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the click event handler you can get a reference to the parent li element of the selected option using

```
e.target.parentNode
```

Now if you loop over the complete list of options

```
document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children")
```

and compare it to the reference you can hide the remaining options.

Here's some code:

```js
var clicked = false;
var allHasChildren = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children a");
for (var x = 0; x < allHasChildren.length; x++) {
  allHasChildren[x].onclick = function(e) {

    var subMenu = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[0];
    if (subMenu.classList.contains('selected')) {
      subMenu.classList.remove("selected");
    } else {
      subMenu.classList.add("selected");
    }
    var allOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children");
    if (!clicked) {
      clicked = true;
      var currentOption = e.target.parentNode;

      for (var a = 0; a < allOptions.length; a++) {
        if (allOptions[a] != currentOption) {
          allOptions[a].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    } else {
      clicked = false;
      for (var a = 0; a < allOptions.length; a++) {
        allOptions[a].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].onmouseout = function() {
  if (clicked && window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0], null).getPropertyValue("display") == "none") {
    var allOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children");
    for (var a = 0; a < allOptions.length; a++) {
      allOptions[a].style.display = "block";
    }

    var subMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu");
    for (var a = 0; a < subMenu.length; a++) {
      subMenu[a].classList.remove("selected");
    }
    clicked = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 55px;
  background: #153161;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: 12px 50px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn i {
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #8391ab;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn .arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #8191aa;
  margin: 100%;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn-two {
  background: red;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn-three {
  background: yellow;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 330px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.selected {
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-one">
            DropDown
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item One</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <div class="hr2"></div>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item Two</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <div class="hr2"></div>
      <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item Two</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is very good, but here is one bug. What If I want comeback to "Main Item Two". In this situation that is imposible. I'm limited to clicking on one menu. if I want to go back, it's impossible

Comment: In this case we need to reset the elements to it's initial state as the mouse leaves the dropdown menu completely. I modified the code in my answer above a little.

Comment: you are perfect, but Can I choose one item by clicking on this item to return all items again. Example , click on "Main Item One" and got sub items. Okey But If i click again on "Main Item One" i got all items "Main Item One, "Main Item Two" .... sorry if I am bored

Comment: Yes that's possible too. We just need to modify the click handler a little to toggle the visibility of the sub menu elements. I changed teh code once more!

Comment: Perfect! Vote up! Thanks!

Comment: No problem Alex - glad I could help!